# How to make a Bash insert script for MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash

I've been trying for two days to make a simple script which feeds an argument (a query) to `mysql -e` for it to execute. But I can't use `mysql -e` inside the script for some reason, here are my testings :

I can run the following line in my bash with success :

```
mysql -u abrouze -p simubase -e "insert into Processing values(1,2,3,'coca cola')"
```

It might be important to note that I need to pass full strings with whitespaces in the values.

Now, here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
req="\"$1\""
echo $req
mysql -u abrouze -p simubase -e $req
```

Escaping quotes here so $req is really surrounded by quotes, and it doesn't work.

Trace :

```
brouze@lasb-ida:~$ ./myrage.sh "insert into Processing values(1,2,3,'huge bear')"
"insert into Processing values(1,2,3,'huge bear')"

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

Following this, the help wall-of-text.

It seems absolutely trivial to me, I absolutely don't know how it would not work...

Comment: `echo ${req} | mysql...` maybe? Your quotes are all wrong. There should _not_ be quotes _in_ the string, they should be _around_ the string. So `req=$1` and then use `"${req}"`.

Comment: As you said `req=$1`,`echo ${req} | mysql...` works. More simply, `echo $1 | mysql...` works too. As for why quotes inside the string is not the same as outside the string, I suppose it's because of Bash's behavior on parsing strings based on the quoting used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for this, have your script be:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u abrouze -p simubase << EOF
$1
EOF
```

Then call your script as before:

```
./myrage.sh "insert into Processing values(1,2,3,'huge bear');"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would like to understand the mechanic though. Since I had provided the exact same string `"insert into..."` to mysql, why did that not work ?